# neo4j - Doesn't link a relation to a node that was create

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j Server version: 3.4.4 (enterprise) and Neo4j Browser version: 3.2.5.

When I run those commands :

```
create (a:DVK {Naam : 'A'}) -[:IS_PROJECT_FOR]->(:DVL {Naam : 'C'})
create (a) -[:IS_PROJECT_FOR]->(:DVL {Naam : 'B'})
```

I have 4 nodes created : A, B, C and another node, and 2 relations. I was expecting to have 3 nodes : A, B, C with 2 relations.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and advice how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I tested your query with Neo4j 3.4.4 enterprise and browser 3.2.5, it creates 3 nodes and 2 relationships as expected. Are you sure this is the query that's creating 4 nodes? Note if you don't reuse the `a` variable you'd get 4 nodes, are you sure the variables match in both creates?

Comment: Also if you have colons at the end of each line they become separate statements, so variables wouldn't remain in scope, watch out for that as well.

Comment: @InverseFalcon : Yes, I used these 2 line statements and I had 4 nodes. For this test I don't reuse the a variable. If I look in the table I see 3 nodes but when I look in the relation ship table I have empty fields (see attachment)

Comment: I don't think your attachment came through, please either retry or modify your question to include it. As for returning relationships, the table view will only show the attribute maps. Check the Code results tab to see what would be available if processing results via the driver. Also as previously mentioned if you aren't reusing a variable (like the `a` variable) in the second create then 4 nodes is expected. CREATE creates the whole pattern, it won't try to first match to elements in the graph, you would need to do that yourself if you want it.

Comment: @InverseFalcon : I made another test - putting the two statements in one query provides me three nodes with two relation ships which is what I expected, but putting 1 statement for one query in my case two queries doesn't provide me the expected results.

Comment: By "1 statement for one query in my case two queries" you mean you executed each line separately? In that case the results are expected. Variables only last for the duration of a query, so when you executed the second create query, `a` was out of scope, it didn't refer to the `a` in the previous query, so it was interpreted as a new variable to bind to a new blank (no label no property) node.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments on the main question, it looks like you executed each query separately, not together in a single query.

Remember that variables are not saved to the database, and only exist for the duration of a single query (or sometimes less if it goes out of scope due to not being included in a WITH clause in the query).

Because of this, for the second query:

```
create (a) -[:IS_PROJECT_FOR]->(:DVL {Naam : 'B'})
```

Nothing is in scope when this is executed, so the `a` here doesn't reference the `a` variable in the previous query. Instead, since this is the first usage of `a` for the query, it will be bound to a newly-created blank node (no labels, no properties), and a :DVL node will be created with the provided property, and then the :IS_PROJECT_FOR relationship added between them.

If the two creates had instead been executed within the same query then `a` from the first create would have still been in scope, and that node would have been the one used when the second create executed.